# Prove the order of differentiation does not matter by integration

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is $C^2$ and $A $ is a open set in $\mathbb R^2$, $f:A\to \mathbb R$. Then $Q\subset A$ is a rectangle.

1. Use Fubini's theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $$ \int_Q \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)  \ d\sigma=\int_Q \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) d\sigma $$
2. Show $$  \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y) =\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) $$  for $(x,y)\in A$

The first part is not hard for me, just by directly saying $Q=[a,b] \times [c,d]$ and using Fubini and the fundamental theorem of calculus, I get both of them being equal to $f(b,d)-f(b,c)-f(a,d)+f(a,c)$

I'm wondering about question 2

I think the first part is a hint for proving the 2nd part, but I know that if the integrations of two functions are equal, this can't imply they are the same. Finally, I got stuck.

My attempt was trying to prove that for all $(x,y), \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)-\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)\equiv 0 $. I failed

Then I thought that  $ \displaystyle \int_Q \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)  \ d\sigma=\int_Q \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) d\sigma $ can be expanded to be

$$  \int_a^b (\int_c^d \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y) \ dy) \ dx=\int_c^d (\int _a^b\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) \ dx ) \ dy $$

Since $f \in C^2$, the order of integration is changeable, so
$$ \int_a^b (\int_c^d \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y) \ dy) \ dx=\int_a^b (\int _c^d\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y) \ dy ) \ dx\implies 
\int_a^b (\int_c^d \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(x,y)-\dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x,y)  \ dy) \ dx =0$$

Then I don't know what I should do. Any help on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part is very easy once you have the first, and realize that the first part is true **for all** rectangles $Q\subset A$.

Suppose for contradiction there is a point $(x_0,y_0)$ where the mixed partials are not equal; then the difference is non-zero at that point. For the sake of definiteness, assume the difference $g=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}-\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x} $is strictly positive at $(x_0,y_0)$ (otherwise just replace $f$ with $-f$). By continuity of $g$, there must exist a closed rectangle $R$ such that $g>0$ on $R$. Therefore, $\int_Rg>0$, which contradicts the first part, which would tell you that $\int_Rg=0$.

Comment: You mean that even though $ g$ can probably not be positive on the entire $A$, we can pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ where $g$ is positive, then by the continuity of $g$, $g$ won't change the sign at a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. We just take a rectangle $R$ in that neighborhood. Then the integration of $g$ on $R$ should be positive, but this contradicts the result in $A$ that on any rectangle in $A$ the integration is zero. This is the main idea, right?

Comment: @Yinky yes (it’s not just the main idea, it’s the entire proof:).

Comment: @ peek-a-boo Thanks!